# pipe after colon in makefile: /home/.ssh/config: | /home/.ssh

Tags: makefile, pipe

what does `|` mean in the following piece of makefile?

```
/home/.ssh:
    install -d -m 700 /home/.ssh

/home/.ssh/config: | /home/.ssh
    echo "$$CONFIG" >> $@

/home/.ssh/credentials: | /home/.ssh
    echo "$$CREDENTIALS" >> $@
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The pipe character declares the relationship to the prerequisite rule to be of an order-only¹ type. Here, if `/home/.ssh` did not exist, it would be created in any case, but if its timestamp changes, none of the other things will happen just because of that.

---

¹: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html